# Can't connect to new Azure SQL Server instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've just spun up an instance Azure SQL server. I can connect to it from the Azure Portal, but I get a timeout error when trying to connect with SQL Management Studio (and other methods):

```
Cannot connect to *server*,*port*.

Additional information:
    A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)
    (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 121)
        The semaphore timeout period has expired
```

I've been searching for a solution but the only thing I find about the error message is that the database is under heavy load, which seems unlikely concidering it was just created!

Anybody know what can cause this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems it was the company firewall that was blocking the traffic. I tried from another network entirely and then I could access the server.

I guess my two alternatives now are either to unblock 1433 in the company firewall, or to open another port in Azure SQL Server, which doesn't seem possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Error 121 has always been considered a network related error as you can read in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/325487/advanced-network-adapter-troubleshooting-for-windows-workstations) Microsoft Support article. The Internet service you receive, network adapters are things you should consider examine.

Please consider to click the "Options" button of SQL Server Management Studio, on the "Connection Properties" tab, try setting a greater value for the "Connection time-out" setting.

If you need to use a Corporate VPN to connect to Azure SQL Database, make sure you are connected to the VPN.

Comment: Thanks. I've made sure to connect from a valid IP and even removed all IP restrictions, so that shouldn't be the problem. And I can connect to the rest of the internet so why not the server?
I don't see how it can take more than 30 seconds to connect, any more than a few hundred milliseconds is unacceptable.
I can't seem to find the Opions button you mentioned.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of SSMS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes. And I've tried multiple ways of connecting. All with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is related to a Firewall in the middle doing SSL inspection.

I Suggest to try requesting your firewall admin to add an exemption on the SSL Inspection engine , or try using another connection not doing SSL inspection.